# Predict the values of variable features over timestamps

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, convolutional-neural-network, transformer

HI i am having a dataset which contain timestamps and number of users at that timestamp. Each user has resource values which change per timestamp. How can i make predictions of number of users incoming at timestamp and the resource values of each user at that timestamp.
I found out that meta-learning model can be used for this proposal. Is there any conv Net or Deep neural networks can solve this proposal

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can use recurrent neural networks, ARIMA and SARIMA forecasting models as well for time series applicaitons, here's a great tutorial provided by Jason Brownlee on using LSTM RNN models
[link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/).